# Stripe integration using actions-on-google generated payment token

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created actions on google application with transaction enabled.

Upon successfully placing an order through assistant I am getting a payment token but it is a base64-encoded string and I dont know how to use it to charge the user using Stripe(payment gateway) api.

in actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION, I am getting response by doing :
const arg = conv.arguments.get('TRANSACTION_DECISION_VALUE');

The token I am getting is in this "arg" object :
arg.order.paymentInfo.googleProvidedPaymentInstrument.instrumentToken

Am I supposed to use this encoded token in Stripe or is there some other token?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you following any code samples or tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while banging my head against the wall on this one I finally found a solution.

```
const token = JSON.parse(new Buffer(arg.order.paymentInfo.googleProvidedPaymentInstrument.instrumentToken, 'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

I took this from here:
https://gist.github.com/thorsten-stripe/9928b11dbf45980af058c3284aafd416#file-index-js-L292